# What is the reason behind (object) term in defining a new class in python?

Tags: python, class, oop

What is the difference between these two methods of defining a class in python:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

and

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

---

I don't understand the role of `(object)` in defining a class and I would appreciate your explanation of it. I did not find any answer to my question looking at the original documentation of python on classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#:%7E:text=Classes%20provide%20a%20means%20of,that%20type%20to%20be%20made.).

Comment: @IainShelvington. It's close, but not the same question. They go well together for sure.

Comment: In Python 3 there is no difference.  It's done automatically.  In Python 2, objects derived from `object` had a few additional capabilities.

Comment: If you are using a recent (still supported) Python version, there is none. If you are using Python 2, upgrade!

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I now understand the reason and apparently it was a duplicate question. 

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. That syntax is used for defining inheritance, but all classes already inherit from `object`.

See [section 9.5. Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance):

> The syntax for a derived class definition looks like this:
>
> ```
> class DerivedClassName(BaseClassName):
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ... all classes inherit from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) ...

---

However, in Python 2, there was a difference. A class without `(object)` would be an old-style class, and one with `(object)` would be a [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class), with more features.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference starting with python 3. Any class that does not explicitly specify base classes inherits from `object`.

The notation `class TestClass(object):` is totally acceptable and unambiguous, but unnecessary and somewhat unconventional for modern code. It's a holdover from python 2.

When new-style classes were being introduced in python 2.2, users had to explicitly inherit from `object` to use the new functionality. Prior to python 3, `class TestClass:` would have created an old-style class, which would have indeed been different. Prior to python 2.2, `object` wasn't a thing.

You can read more about the history of the notation here: [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/2988730)